# Importing data from Oracle by Sqoop to Hive with date format in Oracle

Tags: oracle, hive, sqoop

I want to import a table with date format from oracle database by Sqoop to Hive. I don't understand why imported fields in Hive are string and not timestamp (like Oracle). I prefer to do not use map-colum-hive because i want to do that automaticly for every date format for each table.

This is my Sqoop request :

> sqoop import -D mapDateToTimestamp=true --direct --connect
>   jdbc:oracle:thin:@//$connection --username $username -password
>   $password -m 7 --table $table1 --hive-import --hive-overwrite
>   --hive-database $database1 --hive-table $table2 --where "$date>to_date('$dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')"
>   --null-string '\N' --null-non-string '\N' --target-dir $targetdirectory -- --schema $schema

I tried it with **mapDateToTimestamp = True** and **oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp = True** both, data are imported but data with date format are in string.

Do you have a solution ? suggestions ? advices ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I forgot "Hi everyone !"  ;)

Comment: I encounter this problem today  - unfortunately no answer :(